# jquery - pushing variable into array without alert

Tags: jquery, arrays, push, alert

I am working on a booking calendar which will check against a database for public holiday, I will pass the date to php and php will check against the database, if it exist, jquery will set "styleCls" to 'nice-gray' and if it doesn't, it will set "styleCls" to 'nice-normal'. But somehow it only works if I alert "styleCls", if I remove the alert, the calendar will reflect all "styleCls" to 'nice-gray'. Please help me on this.

```
var styleCls = [];    
var teststyleCls = [];
$('#customercheckoutreview').on('click',function(){
$("#content").load('customercheckout_review.php', function(){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(document).off('click');
});
});

/**
 * nice date picker
*/
(function (global, factory) {
typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined' ? module.exports = factory() :
    typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(factory) :
        (global.niceDatePicker = factory());
}(this, function () {
'use strict';

var niceDatePicker = function ($params) {
    this.$warpper = null;
    this.monthData = null;
    this.$params = $params;
    this.init(this.$params);
};

niceDatePicker.prototype.getMonthData = function (year, month) {
    var year, month;
    var ret = [];

    if (!year || !month) {
        var today = new Date();
        year = today.getFullYear();
        month = today.getMonth() + 1;
    }
    var firstDay = new Date(year, month - 1, 1);
    var firstDayWeekDay = firstDay.getDay();
    if (firstDayWeekDay === 0) {
        firstDayWeekDay = 7;
    }
    year = firstDay.getFullYear();
    month = firstDay.getMonth() + 1;


    var lastDayOfLastMonth = new Date(year, month - 1, 0);
    var lastDateOfLastMonth = lastDayOfLastMonth.getDate();
    var preMonthDayCount = firstDayWeekDay - 1;
    var lastDay = new Date(year, month, 0);
    var lastDate = lastDay.getDate()

    var k=1;

    for (var i = 0; i < 7 * 6; i++) {               
        var date = i + 1 - preMonthDayCount;
        var showDate = date;
        var thisMonth = month;
        var thisYear = year;
        var today = new Date();


        //gray next previous month
        if (date <= 0) {
            thisMonth = month - 1;
            showDate = lastDateOfLastMonth + date;
            styleCls = 'nice-gray';
        } 
        else if (date > lastDate) {
            thisMonth = month + 1;
            showDate = showDate - lastDate;
            styleCls = 'nice-gray';
        } 
        else {
            var today = new Date();
            if (showDate === today.getDate() && thisMonth === today.getMonth() + 1 && thisYear === today.getFullYear()) {
                styleCls = 'nice-current';
            } 
            else if (showDate <= today.getDate() && thisMonth === today.getMonth() + 1) {
                styleCls = 'nice-gray';
            }
            else if ((thisMonth < today.getMonth() + 1) && (thisYear == today.getFullYear())) {
                styleCls = 'nice-gray';
            }
            else if (thisYear < today.getFullYear()) {
                styleCls = 'nice-gray';
            }
            else{
                //gray 3 day before actual day
                if (showDate <= today.getDate() + 2 && thisMonth === today.getMonth() + 1) {
                    styleCls = 'nice-gray';
                }
                else if (Number.isInteger(k/7)) {
                    styleCls = 'nice-gray';
                    if(k==8){
                        k=1;
                    }
                }
                else{
                    //gray ph hpliday
                    var dateToday = showDate;
                    var dateMonth = month;

                    if(dateToday<10) {
                        dateToday = '0'+dateToday;          
                    } 
                    if(dateMonth<10) {
                        dateMonth= '0'+dateMonth;
                    }
                    var checkday = thisYear + '-' + dateMonth + '-' + dateToday;
                    $.get('checkavailableday.php',{checkday:checkday},function(data) {
                        var holiday = JSON.parse(data);
                        if(holiday[0].color == "nice-gray"){
                            window.styleCls = 'nice-gray';
                        }
                        else{
                            window.styleCls = 'nice-normal';
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }           
        k++;
        alert(showDate+"==>"+styleCls+"<==");
        if (thisMonth === 13) {
            thisMonth = 1;
        }
        if (thisMonth === 0) {
            thisMonth = 12;
        }
        ret.push({
            month: thisMonth,
            date: date,
            showDate: showDate,
            styleCls: styleCls
        });
        console.log(ret);
    }
    return {
        year: year,
        month: month,
        date: ret
    };
};

niceDatePicker.prototype.buildUi = function (year, month) {
    this.monthData = this.getMonthData(year, month);
    this.dayWords = [['?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?'], ['Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa', 'Su']];
    this.enMonthsWords = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];

    var html = '<div class="nice-date-picker-warpper">' +
        '<div class="nice-date-picker-header">' +
        '<a href="javascript:;" class="prev-date-btn">&lt;</a>';

    if (!this.$params.mode) {
        this.$params.mode = 'zh';
        html += '<span class="nice-date-title">' + this.monthData.year + '? - ' + this.monthData.month + '?</span>';
    } else if (this.$params.mode === 'en') {
        html += '<span class="nice-date-title">' + this.enMonthsWords[this.monthData.month - 1] + ',' + this.monthData.year + '</span>';
    } else if (this.$params.mode === 'zh') {
        html += '<span class="nice-date-title">' + this.monthData.year + '? - ' + this.monthData.month + '?</span>';
    }

    html += '<a href="javascript:;" class="next-date-btn">&gt;</a>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="nice-date-picker-body">' +
        '<table>' +
        '<thead>' +
        '<tr>';
    if (!this.$params.mode) {
        this.$params.mode = 'zh';
        for (var i = 0; i < this.dayWords[0].length; i++) {
            html += '<th>' + this.dayWords[0][i] + '</th>';
        }
    } else if (this.$params.mode === 'en') {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.dayWords[1].length; i++) {
            html += '<th>' + this.dayWords[1][i] + '</th>';
        }
    } else if (this.$params.mode === 'zh') {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.dayWords[0].length; i++) {
            html += '<th>' + this.dayWords[0][i] + '</th>';
        }
    }
    html += '</tr>' +
        '</thead>' +
        '<tbody>';

    for (var i = 0; i < this.monthData.date.length; i++) {
        if (i % 7 === 0) {
            html += '<tr>';
        }
        html += '<td class="' + this.monthData.date[i].styleCls + '" data-date="' + this.monthData.date[i].showDate + ' ' + this.enMonthsWords[this.monthData.month - 1] + ' ' + this.monthData.year + '">' + this.monthData.date[i].showDate + '</td>';
        if (i % 7 === 6) {
            html += '</tr>';
        }
    }
    html += '</tbody>' +
        '</table>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>';
    return html;
};
niceDatePicker.prototype.render = function (direction, $params) {
    var year, month;
    if (this.monthData) {

        year = this.monthData.year;
        month = this.monthData.month;

    } else {
        year = $params.year;
        month = $params.month;
    }
    if (direction === 'prev') {
        month--;
        if (month === 0) {
            month = 12;
            year--;
        }
    }
    if (direction === 'next') {
        month++;

    }
    var html = this.buildUi(year, month);
    this.$warpper.innerHTML = html;
};
niceDatePicker.prototype.init = function ($params) {
    this.$warpper = $params.dom;
    this.render('', $params);
    var _this = this;
    this.$warpper.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        var $target = e.target;
        if ($target.classList.contains('prev-date-btn')) {
            _this.render('prev');
        }
        if ($target.classList.contains('next-date-btn')) {
            _this.render('next');
        }
        if ($target.classList.contains('nice-normal')) {
            $params.onClickDate($target.getAttribute('data-date'));
        }
    }, false);
    this.$warpper.addEventListener('mouseover', function (e) {
        var $target = e.target;
        if ($target.classList.contains('nice-normal')) {
            $target.classList.add('nice-active');
        }
    }, false);
    this.$warpper.addEventListener('mouseout', function (e) {
        var $target = e.target;
        if ($target.classList.contains('nice-normal')) {
            $target.classList.remove('nice-active');
        }
    }, false);
};
return niceDatePicker;
}));

new niceDatePicker({
dom:document.getElementById('calendar1-wrapper2'),
year:2018,
mode:'en',
onClickDate:function(date){
    document.querySelector('#calendar2-msg').innerHTML=''+date;
}
});
```

Comment: You would need to refactor your code a lot. Async calls in a for loop, when you add alert, it gets enough time to fill your stylecls value. instead do one request to your server(php) and get entire month data in that and in the callback to the request add code to update relevant divs.
I would suggest you go through how async functions work in javascript and bit about using callbacks